# How many ways are there to deal a six-card hand with at most one void in a suit?

Tags: combinatorics

Would it be ${52 \choose 6} - 4{39 \choose 6}$? I feel like this is wrong but I don't really know how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: I don’t follow you. Where does the second term arise from?

Comment: Could you explain what is a "void in a suit"?

Comment: @user: Normally that simply means that the hand contains no cards in that suit. In other words, we want the number of $6$-card hands that contain cards from at least $3$ of the $4$ suits.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: @user: My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

To have at most one void only the following five partitions of the cards are allowed:
$(3,1,1,1); (2,2,1,1); (4,1,1,0); (3,2,1,0); (2,2,2,0) $.

Accordingly, the number of ways to choose the cards is:
$$
\frac {4!}{1!3!}\binom{13}3\binom{13}1^3+\frac {4!}{2!2!}\binom{13}2^2\binom{13}1^2\\
+\frac {4!}{1!2!1!}\binom{13}4\binom{13}1^2
+\frac {4!}{1!1!1!1!}\binom{13}3\binom{13}2\binom {13}1
+\frac {4!}{3!1!}\binom{13}2^3,
$$
which amounts to 18,990,868 or about 93% of all possible hands.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to count the ‘bad’ hands, those with voids in two or three suits, and subtract that figure from $\binom{52}6$, the total number of $6$-card hands.

- If only one suit is represented, there are $4$ ways to choose that suit and $\binom{13}6$ ways to choose a hand from it, so there are $4\binom{13}6$ hands void in three suits.
- If exactly two suits are represented, there are $\binom42=6$ ways to choose the two suits. There are then $\binom{26}6$ ways to choose a hand from those two suits, but that includes the $2\binom{13}6$ hands in which all $6$ cards are from just one of the two suits, and we’ve already counted those in the first bullet point. Thus, the actual number of hands with voids in two suits is $6\left(\binom{26}6-2\binom{13}6\right)$.

Putting the pieces together, we see that there are

$$4\binom{13}6+6\left(\binom{26}6-2\binom{13}6\right)=6\binom{26}6-8\binom{13}6$$

‘bad’ hands and therefore

$$\binom{52}6-6\binom{26}6+8\binom{13}6=18,990,868$$

hands void in at most one suit.